# Remove words from a string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, str-replace

I'm trying to remove some particular words from a given input string which is splitted into words. But from the splitted words array the particular words are not getting replaced.

```
$string = $this->input->post('keyword');  
echo $string; //what i want is you

$string = explode(" ", $string);  

$string = array_values(array_filter(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\']/','', $string)));  

$omit_words = array(' the ',' i ',' we ',' you ',' what ',' is ');  

$keyword = array_values(array_filter(str_ireplace($omit_words,'',$string)));  
print_r($keyword); // Array ([0] => what [1] => i [2] => want [3] => is [4] => you)
```

**Expected output:**

```
Array ([0] => want)
```

I cant find out whats wrong in this. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: If you only need to replace (remove) those words, then a regular expression based approach looks easier. The exploding/array based approach only makes sense, if you really need the words as an array afterwards, not as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all remove spaces from the string in array `$omit_words`.Try this use `array_diff`: If you want to re-index the output you can use `array_values`.

```
$string='what i want is you'; //what i want is you

$string = explode(" ", $string);  

$omit_words = array('the','i','we','you','what','is');  
$result=array_diff($string,$omit_words);

print_r($result); //
```

Comment: perfect... Thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

You can used `array_diff` and then `array_values` for reset array indexing.

```
<?php
$string = $this->input->post('keyword');
$string = explode(" ", $string);  

$omit_words = array('the','i','we','you','what','is');  
$result = array_values(array_diff($string,$omit_words));

print_r($result);  //Array ([0] => want)
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
$string="what i want is you";
$omit_words = array('the','we','you','what','is','i');   // remove the spaces
rsort($omit_words); // need to sort so that correct words are replaced 
$new_string=str_replace($omit_words,'',$string);

print_r($new_string);
```

Comment: expected result should be array not string

Answer (score 1):

You will have to remove spaces from omit_words:

```
$string = "what i want is you";

$string = explode(" ", $string);  

$string = array_values(array_filter(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\']/','', $string)));

$omit_words = array('the','is','we','you','what','i');  

$keyword = array_values(array_filter(str_ireplace($omit_words, '', $string)));
print_r($keyword); // Array ( [0] => want )
```

Comment: No brother.. If i use this code then the word **"wish"** will also reject because it contains **"is"**